# Php and mysql pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make query to mysql, but when i execute it at end of the page i have needless text. How can i delete it?

this is the code:

```
try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM temperature');
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['timestamp'] . "\t" . $row['humidity'] . "\n";
}
?>
```

This is the output:

> 2015-06-16 13:07:47    89 2015-06-16 13:08:46  0 2015-06-16 13:08:56   86 2015-06-16 13:09:06  86 2015-06-16 13:09:16  86 2015-06-16 13:09:27  86 query('SELECT * FROM `temperature`'); while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo $row['timestamp'] . "\t" . $row['humidity'] . "\n"; } } } */?>

Comment: what is the output you desire ?

Comment: *"i have needless text"* - Define "needless". Voted to close as unclear until we do know what you want, and written in your question and NOT in comments. We read code, not minds. ;-)

Comment: Blind stab at this, your ouput doesn't make sense. You sure you're using `.php` extension? Is your computer setup as a webserver with both PHP/MySQL installed? Your question is unclear. another thing... you do have an opening `<?php` tag, right? Gawd, I hate guessing, unless it's "charades".

Comment: well, this question seems to have fallen dead/stale. Moving on; good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see it in the code code you posted but you have a typo in the original: "$stmt = $db->query" has an extra question mark "$stmt = $db-?>query". Or maybe you have commented out an area with html tags and php comments which are incorrectly nested?

Either way, it will break out of PHP parsing and produce the results you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun and different way you could write that loop:

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM temperature') as $row) {
    echo "{$row['timestamp']}\t{$row['humidity']}\n";
}
```

See if doing it that way gets the same issue.